# Marrying an immigrant and siging a prenup

Tags: united-states, immigration, marriage

I've been dating a man who's a Mexican immigrant. We want to get married but he wants me to sign a prenup. He has condos and restaurants and I have nothing right now. Some of his properties and resturants aren't even on his legal name. So I thought it was weird him ask me that. He has an attorney that is writing up a prenup "supposeably" I'm just more confused. I'm just saying a hard time understanding, is that even possible? Could he ask me to sign a prenup while being illegal?

Comment: A person's immigration status is not particularly relevant to whether the person can legally enter into, or be bound by, an agreement.  If his attorney is preparing a document for you to sign then *you should not sign it without having your own attorney first review it.*  You can ask him to give you the money to pay an attorney.

Comment: @TammyArias If you think of people being “illegal”, you probably shouldn’t marry them in the first place, let alone hope for proceeds from them. If someone has genuine intentions to marry out of affection, it’s kinda weird they make a deal about having to sign they would make no more out of a marriage on divorce than what they made themselves in it or before it. I hope he never married you.

Answer (score 1):

The legality of a prenuptial agreement is completely independent of immigration status.

The converse of this proposition is not true. If you get married and have a strict prenuptial agreement the likelihood that immigration officials will treat the marriage as a sham marriage which does not qualify to allow him to receive a spousal visa for immigration purposes is great. While a prenuptial agreement isn't an absolute bar to having a marriage considered to be valid for immigration purposes, the more strict it is, the more likely it is that immigration officials will not recognize the marriage as valid.

> Some of his properties and resturants aren't even on his legal name.

It is hard to know what you mean by this statement. It is common place for people to own companies that own properties and restaurants. It is not common for those properties and restaurants to be owned in the name of another individual who is not clearly held out to the public to be a trustee or fiduciary of some type, although it is probably not illegal for someone to hold property or restaurants in the name of an undisclosed nominee owner for any purpose other than liquor licensing.

> So I thought it was weird him ask me that. He has an attorney that is
>   writing up a prenup "supposeably" I'm just more confused.

If this leaves you feeling weird and confused, you may be thinking of the relationship in a different way than he is thinking of the relationship. He may be seeing you as a temporary stepping stone to citizenship who is not unpleasant, while you may be seeing this as a permanent relationship and life long commitment.

At a minimum, you should absolutely consult your own lawyer before signing anything, and he should offer to provide you funds to do that. If he doesn't, just say no.

Comment: “[She] may be seeing this as a permanent relationship and life long commitment”, right. That’s exactly what she was seeing it as. In the Netherlands, marriages are established on the statutory equivalent of prenups except people don’t divorce as much as in California. Because there is no incentive to it.

Comment: She didn’t even think it’s ok to take advantage of the guy’s immigration status, and be flabbergasted about the flagrancy of her inferior to try and assert rights that a citizen or permanent resident would be able to exercise no problem should he have been on equal standing as her. How is that for a true marriage? Shouldn’t the absence of a prenup raise the concern of USCIS that the marriage is merely for proceeds for a U.S. citizen? The sponsorship should also be a waive-able duty of the citizen spouse. There should be ZERO incentive in marriage other than affection. Zero.